# How firebase-js-sdk logEvent can use Navigator.sendBeacon?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

In this scenario:
`<a href="www.google.com" onClick={() => logEvent(xxxx)}>,` clicking the  tag needs to be reported to firbase, but the page will jump and xhr may fail

what to do `<a href="www.google.com" onClick={() => logEvent(xxxx)}>,`, click the  tag to report to firbase and jump normally